# Future terminating before context.become is applied

Tags: akka

Consider the situation described by the following snippet

```
class MyActor extends Actor {
    def receive = {
        case msg: String =>
            val f: Future[Long] = <some future>
            f pipeTo self
            context.become(afterFuture)
    }

    def afterFuture: Receive = {
        case futureResult: Long =>
            // process the future result
    }
}
```

So, we have an actor that starts the execution of a future, piping it's result to itself. It then changes it's behavior in order to be able to process the future result.
Is there the possibility of the future terminating before the call to context.become can take effect, and therefore the actor being unable to handle the future result?

My guess is that it's not because the handling on the current message (msg: String) will only terminate after context.become has taken effect, at which time the next message in the mailbox will be processed and the new behavior will already be in place. Still, I'd like to get a confirmation from other people certainly more knowledgable than me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your call to `context.become` will be completed before the next message is processed.  There is no race condition in that situation.